# How to take Null values query expression using servlet and jsp

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp

I need to calculate and retrieve data from SQL server database table in my table having the `NoOfErrors` and `NoOfAudited` columns.

I need to calculate the Accuracy based on these columns.

I have a query like this

```
select 
   a.id, 
   (100-((a.NoOfErrors*100)/ NULLIF(a.NoOfAudited,0))) as Accuracy 
from Table1 a 
 join Table2 pd 
   on a.batchid=pd.id 
where 
  a.charge='"+Poster+"' and status=1
```

The above query is executed only when the `NoOfErrors` and `NoOfAudited` columns contain some values.

I have all the values but if a value in any one of the`NoOfErrors` and `NoOfAudited` columns contains `Null` value it doesn't retrieve any data, and it shows `No data found`.

> ResultSet data is not accepting null values

How can I make the query accept null values and retrieve data by replacing null to empty in jsp table?

Answer (score 0):

This line is problematic and should be corrected.

```
   (100-((a.NoOfErrors*100)/ NULLIF(a.NoOfAudited,0))) as Accuracy
```

**problem #1**:

```
NULLIF(a.NoOfAudited,0)
```

if `NoOfAudited` is `NULL` then the expression will return `0`; basically you are dividing by zero. This should be replaced with `1` like below

```
NULLIF(a.NoOfAudited,1)
```

**problem #2**

No checks for NULL value for **NoOfErrors** column.
In SQL server most NULL arithmetic results in `NULL`.
For example all below queries will yield `NULL`

```
select 100-NULL*100/0
select NULL*100
select NULL/0
select 100-NULL
```

Therefore you'll get `NULL` value as `Accuracy` whenever `NoOfErrors` is `NULL`

To correct this part, you should write your query expression like

```
   (100-((COALESCE(a.NoOfErrors,0)*100)/ COALESCE(a.NoOfAudited,1))) as Accuracy
```

Note that I've replaced `NULLIF` with `COALESCE` which is ANSI compliant and will run on both SQL server and MySQL

**TLDR;**

your query should be like

```
select 
   a.id, 
  case 
   when COALESCE(a.NoOfErrors,a.NoOfAudited,'') ='' 
   then''
   else 
    CAST((100-((COALESCE(a.NoOfErrors,0)*100)/ COALESCE(a.NoOfAudited,1))) as VARCHAR(10))as Accuracy
 end
from Table1 a 
 join Table2 pd 
   on a.batchid=pd.id 
where 
  a.charge='"+Poster+"' and status=1
```

Comment: Hi, @DhruvJoshi, removing Null values for your taking it good but when  `both columns having the Null values then Accuracy showing 100` it's not showing correct Accuracy but `i need when both columns having Null values accuracy display in empty`

Comment: @Karthik Please accept my reply as correct answer if it worked for you- so that other users can benefit: from knowing that the answer works and by having the question marked as Answered.